# How can I provide fixed time slots to my resouces in civiBooking?

Tags: civibooking

For Example I have a Room, which I want People to book through civiBooking, but while booking they are given fixed time slots, either booking it for 30 minutes or 1 hour. How can I give fixed time slots to my resources?

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20383/missing-civibooking-resource-config-set suggests that timeslots should be (or were) possible. (just recording my own google outcomes) https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20383/missing-civibooking-resource-config-set